# Show users with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to create a show page as a profile page for each of my users. However, I keep getting undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass as error message whenever I try to show anything in the view.

I'm using Devise to register and store user information. My users are called "artists".

```
/routes.rb

devise_for :artists, controllers: { sessions: "artists/sessions", passwords: "artists/passwords", registrations: "artists/registrations", confirmations: "artists/confirmations",  unlocks: "artists/unlocks"}
resources :artists, only: [:show, :index]

/artists_controller.rb

class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
 def show
  @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
 end
end

/show.html.erb

<%= @artist.username %>
```

I get this error if I try to display email, ID, etc...

Logs

```
Started GET "/artists/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-04 14:00:47 -0500
Processing by ArtistsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Rendered artists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass):
1: <div>
2:   <%= @artist.username %>
3: </div>
4: <div>
5:   <ul>
app/views/artists/show.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_artists_show_html_erb___67732
1755_70508328'


Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (7.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
(4.0ms)
Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8
/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within
rescues/layout (91.0ms)
```

Comment: There must be something else going on here because `ActiveRecord::Base#find` will never return nil (it will raise an error if the record isn't found). What do your logs say about the request parameters?

Comment: Weird. Can you add a `p @artist` right after the `Artist.find` call in the controller? Also, have you stopped and restarted the server? I'm pretty sure this can't happen with the setup you described.

Comment: Alright, so what I did was put the artist views (show) into an artists folder (views/artists/artists/show.html.erb) and put the controller in (controller/artists/artists_controller.rb) and changed the class to (Artists::ArtistsController < ApplicationController) and am able to display the username. But now the routes do not work. Currently have them at (get 'artists/:id' => 'artists/artists#show') which works fine if I manually type it in, but if I try to link to current_artist I get an error undefined method `artist_path'. Looking at rake routes there is no path name for artists/artists#show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're nesting your `ArtistsController` into `/artists`, to get routes to work you need to either use

```
get 'artists/:id' => 'artists/artists#show', as: :artist
```

or

```
resources :artists, controller: 'artists/artists', only: [:show]
```